# ChatBot back to previous dialog

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I've created a chatbot using Node.js and the flow of dialogs works fine til the endDialog.  Im having issues implementing a back option so it can jump back only to previous dialog. Can anyone please guide me how to solve that?

```
  .reloadAction(
    "restartBenefits", "Ok. Let's start over.",
    {
        matches: /^start over$|^restart$/i
    }
)

    .cancelAction(
    "cancelRequest", "Thank you for reaching out, Good bye!",
    {
        matches: /^nevermind$|^cancel$|^cancel.*request/i,
        confirmPrompt: "This will cancel your request. Are you sure?"
    }
);
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code, any error messages, and other necessary information.

Comment: // in each Dialog I have a reload (startover) and cancel action, i need a back action as well, but was not able to find something about it: .reloadAction(
    "restartBenefits", "Ok. Let's start over.",
    {
        matches: /^start over$|^restart$/i
    }
)
.cancelAction(
    "cancelRequest", "Thank you for reaching out, Good bye!",
    {
        matches: /^nevermind$|^cancel$|^cancel.*request/i,
        confirmPrompt: "This will cancel your request. Are you sure?"
    }
);

Comment: Hi @Migena22! Can you edit your post to place this information in it? You can format your post so that code shows clearly. It is very difficult to read in this comment.

Comment: @JJ_Wailes I edited the main post. thnx

Comment: Hi, by 'jump back only to previous dialog', do you mean jump to a previous waterfall step, or jump back to a parent dialog?

Comment: I think he meant parent - right ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`customAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-actions?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#bind-a-customaction)

In this case you can listen for whatever you want to be a keyword for "back" and then simply route the user back to that dialog using `replaceDialog`

```
bot.customAction({
    matches: /back|last/gi, //whatever prompts you want to match.
    onSelectAction: (session, args, next) => {
         session.replaceDialog(PreviousDialog); //variable with the last dialog in it, set that somewhere, such as the end of your previous dialog
    }
})
```

Comment: but, if the dialogue ends, it should automatically go back to parent.  Why would we ask the user to type in `back` or any synonymous word..

Comment: @Gel It's certainly not the only way, but in this case I'm just answering the question as written.

Answer (score 0):

I think that at the final step of the dialog waterfall you need to add the last lines in this sample step:

```js
    /**
     * This is the final step in the main waterfall dialog.
     * It wraps up the sample "book a flight" interaction with a simple confirmation.
     */
    async finalStep(stepContext) {
        // If the child dialog ("bookingDialog") was cancelled or the user failed to confirm, the Result here will be null.
        if (stepContext.result) {
            const result = stepContext.result;
            // Now we have all the booking details.

            // This is where calls to the booking AOU service or database would go.

            // If the call to the booking service was successful tell the user.
            const timeProperty = new TimexProperty(result.travelDate);
            const travelDateMsg = timeProperty.toNaturalLanguage(new Date(Date.now()));
            await stepContext.context.sendActivity(ActivityFactory.fromObject(this.lgTemplates.evaluate('BookingConfirmation', {
                Destination: result.destination,
                Origin: result.origin,
                DateMessage: travelDateMsg
            })));
        }

        // =====> HERE: Restart the main dialog with a different message the second time around
        return await stepContext.replaceDialog(this.initialDialogId, { restartMsg: 'What else can I do for you?' });
    }
```

Just change the `this.initialDialogId` accordingly.